# Subtract current row from previous row, keeping previous row value as constant -- SQL

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, lag

Table product has average revenue by product

| product | avg_rev |
| --- | --- |
| A | 500 |
| B | 400 |
| C | 250 |
| D | 100 |

Table product_diff, is where I need to calculate, diff_a as another column where formula a-a, a-b, a-c, a-d carries over.

| product | avg_rev | diff_a |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 500 | 0 |
| B | 400 | 100 |
| C | 250 | 250 |
| D | 100 | 400 |

My query so far:
`select product, avg_rev, lag(avg_rev,1) over (order by product) as previous_value from product;`

I can take difference between previous row minus current row by saying `previous_value-avg_rev` but what I need is for previous row to be constant, minus current row as carried over all the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the difference of `avg_rev` of the 1st product with the current row's `avg_rev`:

```
SELECT product, 
       avg_rev, 
       FIRST_VALUE(avg_rev) OVER (ORDER BY product) - avg_rev AS diff_a 
FROM product;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8ca24fcb10195f0c9a3febea6cfe1bd3).
Results:

| product | avg_rev | diff_a |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 500 | 0 |
| B | 400 | 100 |
| C | 250 | 250 |
| D | 100 | 400 |

Comment: Thanks, this would work but what if I want to create similar columns for other products as constant. So, as diff_a = a-a, a-b, a-c, a-d, what if I want to create diff_b = b-a, b-b, b-c, b-d and so on for all products i.e. diff_c, diff_d?

Comment: @RashItIs check the 2nd query here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=69fc1fe2d244be313e89c253a316c3fb

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want one of the products, I would use conditional logic:

```
select product, avg_rev,
       avg_rev - max(case when product = 'A' then avg_rev end) over () as diff_a
from product;
```

Comment: Thanks, this might work if I want to create similar columns for other products as constant. So, as diff_a = a-a, a-b, a-c, a-d, what if I want to create diff_b = b-a, b-b, b-c, b-d and so on for all products i.e. diff_c, diff_d?

Comment: @RashItIs . . . Just repeat the logic for additional columns, changing the `when` clause.

Comment: @RashItIs . . . Then why didn't you accept this answer?  The other answer only works for the first product alphabetically, which is not what you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff maybe because the other answer answers the question as it is phrased. Anything else was mentioned in the comments and answered in the comments.

Comment: Sorry, I missed accepting it. It did help then, thanks again.